# Using java to get the current process owner

Tags: java, unix

I want to know the owner of current process in Unix using Java. I want to find the current server's owner name. I tried with running "who am i" command in Runtime.getRuntime().exec(), but its not returning me any results.

```
String line = ""; 
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("who am i");
InputStream iStream = p.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(iStream);
BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
while ((line = bufReader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println("Input "+line);
}
```

Is there anything wrong with this code or any idea how can I find the owner of current process using Java?

Comment: You need sudo for that, right?

Comment: @assylias I think you should pst that as an answer...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First thing, I think `System.getProperty("user.name")` should work for that

Second thing, the reason your code is not returning anything is because the command is `whoami` with NO SPACES so your exec line should be (assuming you are running on windows through cygwin or on a **nix based system)

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("whoami");
```

Comment: `who am i` is fine as well. [man who](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?who+1)

Comment: `who am i` returns blank on my system

Comment: If you didn't have `who`, you would have read something like `bash: command not found`. Does `which who` return blank as well? (assuming you're on Unix/BSD/Mac/Linux)